# why [object HTMLImageElement] is displayed ? not <img>?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, rss

I try to parse rss feed from a tumblr blog.
this is a snippet of the xml from rss feed.

```
<item>
    <title>title goes here</title>
    <description>
        <img src="http://media.tumblr.com/ajfafh.jpg"/>
        <p>text description goes here</p>
    </description>
    .
    .
</item>
```

i try this code to get img tag within description tag

```
function parse(xml){
    xml.find('item').each(function(index){
        var $item = $(this);
        var df = $item.find('description')[0].textContent;
        var $asdf = $(df).find('img').first()[0];

        var item = {
            index: index,
            description: $item.find('description')[0].textContent,
            img: $asdf
        }

        console.log(item.img);// return exactly the img tag just like what i want <img>
        // i also try this one
        console.log($(item.description).find('img').first());// return [<img src />]

        this.container.append(Mustache.to_html(this.template, item));
        //this.container = $('#container')
        //this.template = $('#template')
    });
}
```

i use mustache.js to load it to html.
the HTML

```
<ul id="container">
    <script id="template" type="text/template">
    <li>{{img}}</li>
    </script>
</ul>
```

but when i run it on browser it returns [object HTMLImageElement], while console.log() returns correct value.
why is that happen? what did i miss?

Comment: you should really revise your naming conventions...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're `log`ing item.img, but you're trying to append `item`. I imagine you want to append `item.img` instead.